# how can I get something in Object with a Array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to change value in a Object,but this Object is nest,like this

```
Obj = {
  'a': {
    'b': {
      'c': {
        'name': 'bob'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and there is a Array:
`['a','b','c']`
I want get `name` with this array
how can I change this array to `obj['a']['b']['c']['name']`?
Must consider the nested object different layers？
how can I do this?

Comment: `obj[arr[0]][arr[1]][arr[2]]['name']`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/7mhvo8m3/

Comment: `obj[arr[0]][arr[1]][arr[2]]['name'] ='new value'`

Answer (score 2):

Or in pure javascript :

```
['a','b','c', 'name' ].reduce(function( t , v ){ return t[v];} , Obj)
```

```js
el = document.getElementById('dbg');
var json = function(val){ return JSON.stringify(val) };
var log = function(val){el.innerHTML += '<div><pre>' + val + '</pre><div>'}

/****************************************************************/

var Obj = {
  'a': {
    'b': {
      'c': {
        'name': 'bob'
      }
    }
  }
}


var keyPath = ['a','b','c', 'name' ];

var result = keyPath.reduce(function( transformed , value){
  
  return transformed[value];
  
} , Obj)

log( 'result\t : ' +  result  )

/***************************************************************/

// we can do also something like that :

var Obj2 = {
  'a': {
    'b': {
      'c': {
        'name': ['bob' , 'marc' , 'jane' , 'lisa']
      }
    }
  }
}

var keyPath2 = 'a.b.c.name.2'

var result2 = keyPath2.split('.').reduce(function( transformed , value){
  
  return transformed[value];
  
} , Obj2)

log( 'result2\t : ' + result2 )

/***************************************************************/
// and using it in a function

var ns = function( keyPath , context , splitter){
  var _keyPath = keyPath.split(splitter|| '.');
  
  return _keyPath.reduce(function( transformed , value){
  
    return transformed[value];
  
  } , context)
  
};

var keyPath3 = 'a.b.c.name.3'; 
var result3 = ns( keyPath3 , Obj2 );

log( 'result3\t : ' + result3)
```

```html
<div id='dbg'><div>
```

Answer (score 1):

That's a classic case for [lodash](http://www.lodash.com), specifically the _.get method

```js
var Obj = {
  'a': {
    'b': {
      'c': {
        'name': 'bob'
      }
    }
  }
}

var keyPath = ['a','b','c'];

alert(_.get(Obj, keyPath).name);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.10.1/lodash.js"></script>
```